# File uploaded to destination but name not saved in db in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am trying to upload Receivers name and his photo in database. Picture is uploaded in uploads folder successfully but not in database.Here is my code.

My Html code

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload');?>

<div class="form-row">
 <div class="form-group col-md-4">
  <label class="label_color" for="inputState">Receiver Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCity" name="receiver_name">
</div>
<div class="form-row">
 <div class="form-group col-md-4 upload-border float-left">
  <label class="label_color" for="inputState">Picture Upload</label>
  <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20">
  <input class="mt-4" type="submit">
</div>
```

My code in controller.php

```
public function do_upload(){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('record_number', 'Record Number', 'required');

    $data= array(
    'record_number' => $this->input->post('record_number'),
    'pic' => $this->input->post('userfile')
   );
        $config = array(
        'upload_path' => './uploads/',
        'allowed_types' => "gif|jpg|jpeg|png|iso|dmg|zip|rar|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|ppt|pptx|csv|ods|odt|odp|pdf|rtf|sxc|sxi|txt|exe|avi|mpeg|mp3|mp4|3gp",
        'max_size' => "2048000", // Can be set to particular file size , here it is 2 MB(2048 Kb)
        'max_height' => "950",
        'max_width' => "1250"
);
```

file upload is working fine. whereas name of file is not saved in database column.A column is already defined in database.

```
$insert = $this->upload_model->insert_form('upload_table', $data);

    if ($insert == true) {
        echo "file Submitted";
    }else{
    echo "file submit failed";
   }
```

Upload_model.php
    class Upload_model extends CI_Model{

```
    public function insert_form($tablename , $data){

    if ($this->db->insert($tablename, $data)) {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

*After upload file use this*

```
$this->upload->data('file_name');
```

*Instead of this :*

```
$this->input->post('userfile')
```

Your `$data` variable should be like this :

**Note** : assign value in `$data` when upload is  is successful (after `$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')`)

```
$data= array(
'record_number' => $this->input->post('record_number'),
'pic' => $this->upload->data('file_name')
);
```

for more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html#CI_Upload::data